# Connecting to MySQL container in jenkins pipeline

Tags: java, mysql, docker

I am trying to run some integration tests in my Jenkins pipeline connecting to a mysql docker container. For some reason, we can't connect to it. We have checked that the credentials are right and that the port is exposed to the host:

```
mysql:5.6     0.0.0.0:3360->3306/tcp   mysql
```

Our Jenkins runs in a host, it isn't a docker container.

I have inspect the container, and everything is the same as in my local environment, where I can connect to the container. This is the error I am getting:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Any idea what it could be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in `jenkins` server, did you connect to port 3360 on target machine ? using `telnet` or `curl`

Comment: With the MySQL container running, SSH into the Jenkins box. From there telnet to the MySQL container. Is it able to make a connection?

Comment: I think the problem is that in my jenkins pipeline, at the start, a container is created, where everything runs, we have an agent {  dockerfile {} }, and then, I run a container in the pipeline.

Comment: Do you run the Jenkins instance and Docker on the same machine? What do you mean by "a container is created"? Do you create a docker container as a part of your pipeline and try to connect to the MtSQL container from the inside of the created container? Please provide more details.